# What is the best way to display and hide pictures in python?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I would like to write a program from which I can launch pictures and video display. Once a new picture or video is called, the previous one has to go.
I don't know what is the best practice for this situation.

Using eog or feh, I can display pictures but as long as the picture is displayed, the script is waiting. 
I manage to write this little solution using Popen and kill but it doesn't seem so efficient. (currently, I'm testing the script with the time.sleep function but eventually the new pictures will be called differently)

```py
import subprocess
import time
from subprocess import call
from subprocess import Popen

photo = Popen(["eog", "--fullscreen"])
call(["eog", "valentin.jpg"]) #display valentin
time.sleep(3)
photo.kill()

photo = Popen(["eog", "--fullscreen"])
call(["eog", "pierre.jpg"]) #display pierre
time.sleep(3)
photo.kill()
```

I would like to know a cleaner way to achieve this goal. Find a way to have the python script constantly running in the background so I don't have to kill eog every time that I need to display a new picture.

Comment: write own viewer in Python. Use one of GUI frameworks: Tkinter, PyQt, wxPython, PyGtk, etc..